# Failed to inject EJB using OpenEJB in Junit

Tags: annotations, ejb, code-injection, openejb

I decided to use TomEE OpenEJB in my Junit test simply because IBM's EmbeddedEJBContainer is too limited. For example, it doesn't support MDB.

So, I added a number of dependencies into my Maven POM.xml and got all necessary OpenEJB jars into my test code. In the BeforeClass method I created the EmbeddedContainer:

```
testEJBContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
```

And this was successful. So, I thought the @EJB annotation for injection would also work. But it didn't. Then I went on to interrogate the JNDI contexts used by OpenEJB. I found my EJB reference was bounded in the following sub-contexts like:

"java:global/MyModule/MyEJB!com.company.dept.MyEJB"   and "java:global/MyModule/MyEJB"

So, they were there. However, the @EJB annotation injection failed. So, I went on to search for tomcat annotation implementation for the EJB annotation method. I wasn't able to find that.

Wondering what may be wrong here. A few things I can think of:

1. The jar containing the @EJB annotation for OpenEJB is not called. That is, some other jar implementing javax.ejb.EJB intercepted tomcat's call.
2. The subcontext name is wrong.

I wanted to bind the MyEJB reference myself to the JNDI context for the injection to work but not able to match up the actual sub-context name. Could you please point me to the right direction?

Sincerely,

Student_101

Comment: I executed the tomee example project and it worked. The JNDI context name used in that project is "java:global/injection-of-ejbs/DataReader." So my next step is to try out whether I can use the @EJB annotation to look up for the first DataReader EJB itself or not.

Comment: It didn't work in the way I put it. Why can't I just follow what the example did to use the @EJB annotation for the DataReader itself? Why do I have to fetch it from the context in the first place?

Comment: public class EjbDependencyTest extends TestCase {

 @EJB
 DataReader dataReader;
 
    public void test() throws Exception {
        final Context context = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer().getContext();

        //DataReader dataReader = (DataReader) context.lookup("java:global/injection-of-ejbs/DataReader");

        assertNotNull(dataReader);

        assertEquals("LOCAL:42", dataReader.readDataFromLocalStore());
        assertEquals("REMOTE:42", dataReader.readDataFromRemoteStore());
        assertEquals("LOCALBEAN:42", dataReader.readDataFromLocalBeanStore());
    }
}

Comment: It looks like the Junit TestCase is not part of the OpenEJB injection logic - that's why the injection doesn't take place.